# Typescript: TSX files show up blank in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, typescript

When attempting to debug a TypeScript application in Google Chrome, the *.ts files are source mapped properly in the inspectors, but the *.tsx files appear totally empty, which doesn't really help me debug them.

How can I get *.tsx files to source map correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to try add MIME type for *.tsx files for used web server.

In case your project is hosted on IIS try to add this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".tsx" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".tsx" mimeType="application/javascript" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hm. I'm currently using Visual Studio, which does it's own sort of thing. Any idea how to find more information?

Comment: When you say Visual Studio I assume you are using IIS Express which is default in VS. In that case there should be Web.config in your project - see edited answer ...

Comment: Ah, nice! I didn't realize that VS used IIS. Thanks, that worked beautifully.

Comment: For some reason, I'm doing exactly this in Visual Studio 2015 for a .NET Core 1.1.0 app and I still get a 404 for my .tsx files.

Comment: Don't forget the `xdt:Transform="Insert"` attribute on `staticContent` if you have more than one web.config using `<system.webServer>`

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to make the web.config based solution work in my .NET Core app. So, I used `IApplicationBuilder.UseStaticFiles`. Since the purpose is just to use TypeScript source maps for development, I made it only serve the files when the app is in development mode.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        var options = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            // Replace "Scripts" with the path to your TypeScript folder
            // (this is also a workaround for the fact that we don't keep TypeScript files under wwwroot)
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Scripts")),
            RequestPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Scripts"),
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
        };
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, telling chrome the right mimeType does indeed solve the issue!

For an **Apache server** include this in your httpd.conf

`AddType application/javascript .tsx`

Answer (score 0):

Foe Windows with IIS, goto IIS Manager, open the Site and in Mime Types add
.TSX with "application/javascript"

also check .ts (for some sort of video associations) and replace with "application/javascript"