# In chrome devtools, in all my tsx source files, syntax highlighting and intellisense no longer work

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools, tsx

Debugging functionalities are not working anymore for me in files with a .tsx extention.

It is working as normal when debugging a .ts file:
[image]

Source maps are unchanged from when it was still working.
However **.tsx** files now look like this.. 
All the **code is black** rather than styled to indicate differences between keywords / strings etc .. And when debugging (which does work) I **cannot hover** variables to see their value.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit: I once solved this by sending content type headers as explained in answer below. But the problem is back now even though when I open the source file in a new tab I can see Content-Type is "application/javaScript"

Comment: did you use webpack/babel? if so, please attach the config file.

Comment: If it used to work and now doesn't (despite showing the correct content type), I'd recommend filing an issue on Chromium.

Answer (score 4):

Finally managed to solve this.

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962981/977206), if you manually let your webserver return the right mime-type for tsx files, chrome will show them with colors and allows proper debugging again.

for me, For an Apache server I included this in httpd.conf

`AddType application/javascript .tsx`

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue (same symptoms) and the solution that worked for you doesn't for me.

Comment: @Niitaku quite a bit later, but check updated answer in case this happens again for you